# Remove console.logs and debugger from code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, eslint

How can we remove logs and debuggers from a react application? Also after removing all logs and debuggers is there any es-lint rule which I can turn ON to prevent the application to run if it contains logs and debuggers?
I've more than 100 console.logs and debugger in my application and I don't want to remove it manually.

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-grep-command-in-linux-unix/

Answer (score 1):

> Also after removing all logs and debuggers is there any es-lint rule
> which I can turn ON to prevent the application to run if it contains
> logs and debuggers?

You can do this by adding the following lines in your ESLint configuration file, such as .eslintrc.json:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "no-console": "error",
    "no-debugger": "error"
  }
}
```

"no-console": "error" means that ESLint will generate errors for every use of console methods in the code.

> How can we remove logs and debuggers from a react application?

1. Search for all instances of console.log, console.debug,
   console.error, and debugger in your code.
2. Remove or comment them out.
3. After doing this, verify that the application is still working as
   expected.

Comment: yeah, it will work but that's a manual way. Is there any extension or linter command that can do the same work for me?